# How can I have a unique INT primary key for a table spread over multiple geographical locations using sql azure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database, data-synchronization

I have an `Organization table` and a `Site table` in my database.

The application is installed at various `Geographical Sites` and each Site has its own Local Database.

I am using `Sql Azure Synchronization Group` for synchronizing all the Sites data once every week. It is fine for all other data to get synchronized in a week, but this one table `Site` - Whenever a new Site is inserted, I need a unique identifier for this site - I know I can use `GUID` which I have used at other places, but there is a requirement for using `INT` only.

If I use `INT`, its possible that same `INT` key is inserted at different locations, which upon synchronization, will result in overwritten records and lost `Sites`.

What can I do for having a unique `INT` primary key for each record inserted in this table ?

Please tell me any possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are separate databases, so the only way SQL Azure will provide a unique Site ID is via Guid. Maybe you could stage a simple WCF service for issuing sequential INTs for you, which you'd call before creating a site (and maybe it keeps its "next id" in a Table row, or something like that. You'd have to make your WCF service either Singleton or capable of issuing multiple IDs without reusing IDs. You may have the occasional unused site INT, since it's possible something goes wrong with the code calling the WCF service, but if you're ok with gaps in your IDs, this shouldn't matter.